# AtLeast occurrences in list

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function that returns the list of elements that appeared at least n times in a list. It should work like this:

```
ghci> atLeast [4,5,2,5,4,3,1,3,4] 2
```

output: `[5,3,4]`

My code:

```
count:: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
count n [] = 0
count n (h:t) | n == h = 1 + count n t
              | otherwise = count n t

atLeast :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
atLeast list min = nub $ filter (\b-> count b list >= min) list
```

Comment: So ... you're done? As far as I can see your code is working. What's your question?

Comment: It looks fine. Perhaps, not as efficient as it could be, since I think using `Data.Map` could speed it up. But, without library support, this looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more efficient way to write this which gives the result you specified is:

```
atLeast :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
atLeast list min = map head $ filter (\list -> length list >= min) $ groupBy (==) $ sortBy (flip compare) list
```

eg.

```
> atLeast [4,5,2,5,4,3,1,3,4] 2                                                                                                                                                                   
[5,4,3]
```

Comment: You could be even more efficient by replacing `length ... >= ... ` by `not null . drop (min-1)`. That way you don't have to count ALL the elements of a group.

Answer (score 0):

## Composing standard functions

As *pikapika* points out in another answer, it's possible to achieve the desired result by composing functions from the base library.

At first glance, a function like `group` from `Data.List` looks promising, but the problem is that it only groups consecutive runs:

```
Prelude Data.List> group [4,5,2,5,4,3,1,3,4]
[[4],[5],[2],[5],[4],[3],[1],[3],[4]]
Prelude Data.List> group [4,4,2,5,5,3,1,3,4]
[[4,4],[2],[5,5],[3],[1],[3],[4]]
```

In order to get the desired behaviour, then, you first have to sort the input:

```
Prelude Data.List> sort [4,5,2,5,4,3,1,3,4]
[1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5]
```

That's better: now you can group it:

```
Prelude Data.List> group $ sort [4,5,2,5,4,3,1,3,4]
[[1],[2],[3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5]]
```

Note, however, that this entails two passes over the the data. The first pass over the list is when you `sort` it. The second pass is when you `group` the output of the first pass.

Unfortunately, you aren't done yet. Now you need to filter that list of lists:

```
Prelude Data.List> filter (\xs -> 2 <= length xs) $ group $ sort [4,5,2,5,4,3,1,3,4]
[[3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5]]
```

or, if you like point-free style better, you can *eta reduce* it:

```
Prelude Data.List> filter ((2 <=) . length) $ group $ sort [4,5,2,5,4,3,1,3,4]
[[3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5]]
```

Finally, you need to extract the common value of each nested list. In general, while `head` is unsafe, we should feel confident that none of the lists are empty:

```
Prelude Data.List> map head $ filter ((2 <=) . length) $ group $ sort [4,5,2,5,4,3,1,3,4]
[3,4,5]
```

One detail about this implementation is that values arrive in ascending order.

This sort of implementation is probably good enough for most purposes, but it *could* be considered inefficient, with at least three list traversals. For lengthy lists, this could be a problem.

To be clear, as always when the discussion is about performance: *measure!*

## Counting as a fold

For short lists, the following is hardly more efficient, but for long lists with few possible values, using fewer passes could be better. So let's see if we can do that.

The strategy I'll use is to accumulate a list of tuples, where each tuple will contain the value, and the number of times it has been observed. For the OP input values `[4,5,2,5,4,3,1,3,4]`, we'll need something like this as an intermediary result:

```
[(4,3),(5,2),(2,1),(3,2),(1,1)]
```

First, we're going to need a function that adds a number to an accumulator like that. When accumulation starts, the list will be empty, but later, a number may already exist in the accumulator. One way to look up a number is to use the `partition` function:

```
*Q50887054> partition ((5 ==) . fst) [(5,2),(2,1),(4,1)]
([(5,2)],[(2,1),(4,1)])
```

Here you have a partially accumulated list of numbers, indicating that you've encountered `5` twice, and `2` and `4` once. Now you want to add another `5`, so you partition the list on the `fst` element of the tuple being equal to five. The result is a tuple where the first element is all the matches (or *hits*) and the second element is a list of those values that don't match.

Using `import Data.Bifunctor`, you can map over the `first` element of that tuple. Inside that map, you have a list of tuples. In practice, this list will either be empty, or have exactly one element, but it's easy enough to deal with the general case where there's an arbitrary number of tuples: extract the `snd` element of all the `hits` and `sum` over the numbers, then add `1` for the new value you just found. Create a tuple of that new count, with the number to add as the key:

```
*Q50887054> first (\hits -> (5, (sum $ snd <$> hits) + 1)) $ partition ((5 ==) . fst) [(5,2),(2,1),(4,1)]
((5,3),[(2,1),(4,1)])
```

This returns a tuple where the first element is a value, and the second element is a list. You can uncurry the cons operator to make a single list out of that tuple:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Bifunctor

tally :: (Num t, Eq a) => a -> [(a, t)] -> [(a, t)]
tally k = uncurry (:) . first (\hits -> (k, sum (snd <$> hits) + 1)) . partition ((k ==) . fst)
```

Here's how you'd begin to `tally` the list `[4,5,2,5,4,3,1,3,4]`. You start with an empty accumulator and the first value in the list, `4`:

```
*Q50887054> tally 4 []
[(4,1)]
```

The accumulator is now `[(4,1)]`, indicating that you've seen `4` once. Moving on to the next element in the input list, `5`, you now `tally` that with the accumulator:

```
*Q50887054> tally 5 [(4,1)]
[(5,1),(4,1)]
```

You now continue using the new accumulator with other values of the list:

```
*Q50887054> tally 2 [(5,1),(4,1)]
[(2,1),(5,1),(4,1)]
*Q50887054> tally 5 [(2,1),(5,1),(4,1)]
[(5,2),(2,1),(4,1)]
```

Notice that at this point, we've seen `5` twice.

Instead of going through this manually, we can use `tally` with `foldl'`:

```
*Q50887054> foldl' (\acc x -> tally x acc) [] [4,5,2,5,4,3,1,3,4]
[(4,3),(3,2),(1,1),(5,2),(2,1)]
```

We're not quite done yet, but now we have a list that we can easily `filter` and `map`:

```
*Q50887054> map fst $ filter ((2 <=) . snd) $ foldl' (\acc x -> tally x acc) [] [4,5,2,5,4,3,1,3,4]
[4,3,5]
```

Polishing up the code a bit, you can make that a function as well:

```
atLeast :: (Ord a, Num a, Eq b, Foldable t) => a -> t b -> [b]
atLeast n = map fst . filter ((n <=) . snd) . foldl' (flip tally) []
```

Here's some examples:

```
*Q50887054> atLeast 1 [4,5,2,5,4,3,1,3,4]
[4,3,1,5,2]
*Q50887054> atLeast 2 [4,5,2,5,4,3,1,3,4]
[4,3,5]
*Q50887054> atLeast 3 [4,5,2,5,4,3,1,3,4]
[4]
*Q50887054> atLeast 4 [4,5,2,5,4,3,1,3,4]
[]
```

Compared to the above solution made from composing standard functions, this implementations only passes over the input list twice: once to fold it, and once to map and filter it.

On the other hand, the `tally` function passes over the accumulator multiple times, so which approach will be faster will most likely depend on the size and range of the input.

I must admit that I've measured neither option...